# How to replace only a part of url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, replace

I need to modify a generated joomla url to another and htaccess seems like a nice way to do this. It's just that I'm not too familiar with it :/

I need to make this url:

```
http://www.site.com/component/uddeim/?task=new&recip=190&nouserlist=141
```

Rewritten into this url:

```
http://www.site.com/community/messages?task=new&recip=190&nouserlist=141
```

`?task=new&recip=190&nouserlist=141` << the number values are dynamic, meaning they change

anyone can help? Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean that your end users will enter `/component/uddeim/?...` into their browsers, use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^component/uddeim/? http://example.com/community/messages [L,QSA,R=301]
```

The `QSA` flag indicates that the original query string should be appended to the new URL, preserving it in whatever for it may be in.

Comment: it doesn't work :( I still see the old url in the address bar... maybe I explained myself wrong. I mean, the generated link is:
http://www.site.com/component/uddeim/?task=new&recip=190&nouserlist=141
I want that when I click the link (or copy and paste it into the browser) it converts in:
http://www.site.com/community/messages?task=new&recip=190&nouserlist=141

PS. Both links work and open the same page.

Comment: @user1010703 So you want a redirect, not an invisible rewrite. Since they're the same page, the rewrite rule above would have no visible effect if it is working.  Add the `[R=301]` flag to redirect.

Comment: thanks .. it got redirected, but not to the right url..
from this: http://www.site.com/component/uddeim/?task=new&recip=190&nouserlist=74 it got redirected into: http://www.site.com/var/www/vhosts/vm1179.cs11.seeweb.it/site.com/community/messages?task=new&recip=190&nouserlist=74
did I do something wrong?

Comment: i think i did it! :)

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^component/uddeim/? http://www.site.com/community/messages [L,QSA,R=301]

THANK YOU!!

ps/i wanted to give you a point for the answer, but it won't let me because i have low reputation :P